# How to query elements from a list of items in wikidata?

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-query-service

There is a list of proper names of stars here: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1433418

How can I query this in the Wikidata Query Service so that all individual names of stars are listed, alongwith other data in the list, such as Constellation?

In other words, how do I get at the members of the list? "Instance of" doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a confusion here coming from the fact that this List of proper names of stars (Q1433418) is an element centralizing links to Wikipedia pages playing this role in the different Wikipedia editions but isn't really playing any meaningful role in Wikidata: there are no instance of ([P31](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31)) List of proper names of stars (Q1433418) in Wikidata.

You would have more luck looking for instance of (P31) Stars ([Q523](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q523)) and instance of elements that are a subclass of ([P279](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P279)) Star, a pattern that you will find in many of the [SPARQL query examples](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples): `?star wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q523 .`

That could give [this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fstar%20%3FstarLabel%20%3Fconstellation%20%3FconstellationLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%23%C2%A0instance%20of%20%28P31%29%20star%20and%20instance%20of%20subclass%20of%20%28P279%29%20star%0A%20%20%3Fstar%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ523%20.%0A%20%20%23%20P59%20%20%3A%20constellation%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fstar%20wdt%3AP59%20%3Fconstellation%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2Cfr%22%20%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%7D%0A%0ALIMIT%205000) ([json version](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?format=json&query=SELECT%20%3Fstar%20%3FstarLabel%20%3Fconstellation%20%3FconstellationLabel%20%3FspectralClass%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%23%20instance%20of%20(P31)%20star%20and%20instance%20of%20subclass%20of%20(P279)%20star%0A%20%20%3Fstar%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ523%20.%0A%20%20%23%20P59%3A%20constellation%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fstar%20wdt%3AP59%20%3Fconstellation%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20%23%20P215%3A%20spectral%20class%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fstar%20wdt%3AP215%20%3FspectralClass%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2Cfr%22%20%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%7D%0A%0ALIMIT%205000%0A)).

And if you're into JS, you can parse the JSON result with this function I wrote: [wdk.simplifySparqlResults](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-sdk#simplify-sparql-results)

Comment: Thank you! I was on a wild-goose chase due to that confusion. And another thanks for the query and parser. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would not take official names of stars from there. The Wikipedia is one of the most useful resources to get first hand, somewhat organised information, on any topic. It is irreplaceable for this, and it would be a great mess not having it. However, the information is very sensitive to misuse caused by vandalism or clumsy editors.

To get (the only) official proper names of stars, the IAU is making an effort started this year. I would use this as reference. It is also stored in a text file which is easy to retrieve by a program, and is being updated while the Committee accepts more star names. It is here:

http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~emamajek/WGSN/IAU-CSN.txt

In fact, as you see, the file structure is presented in a format ready to use by software applications. It has been made to meet needs as yours.

Comment: Thank you! While it doesn't answer the programming side of the question, it solves the goal I am actually trying to achieve.